# Why won't the material node displacement work in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modeling

I have a plane in blender with a image texture node, connected to a RGB to black and white node connected to a multiplier before being connected to the displacement of the *Material Output* node. There appears to be some shadowing on the plane but it is only this that changes when I change the multiplier, the plane while viewed from the side rendered is still totally flat. Do I need to bake this in some way? Or have I totally misunderstood how displacement textures are supposed to work?

Comment: This explains why I just discovered that a displacement map loaded into an image texture node connected to the displacement input of a Material Output node does not seem to need extra mesh data (as would be excpeted ) it is in fact just a bump map.

Answer (score 18):

Change the [displacement type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html?#true-displacement) found in the Properties window under Object Data from (the default) *Bump* to *True*.

Note that this is an *[experimental feature](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html#cycles-experimental-features)* and you must change the feature set from *Supported* to *Experimental* in *Properties > Render Settings > Render*.

> **True Displacement**: Mesh vertices will be displaced before rendering, modifying the actual mesh. This gives the best quality results, if the mesh is finely subdivided. As a result this method is also the most memory intensive.
>
> **Bump Mapping**: When executing the surface shader, a modified surface normal is used instead of the true normal. This is a quick alternative to true displacement, but only an approximation. Surface silhouettes will not be accurate and there will be no self shadowing of the displacement.

Comment: Could you please add a summery of the web page to your answer? If the  site goes down, so does the answer.

Comment: @CharlesL, the link wasn't the answer, it just provided descriptions of the settings. But now included per your request. ;)

Comment: In Houdini, you can apply a displacement map that will do true displacement at render time, but doesn't require you to subdivide the mesh. Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: @Justin It is now. Tick the `Use Subdivision` checkbox and have a subdiv modifier set to be only visible at render time

Comment: Where is the `Use Subdivision` checkbox? And to make the subdiv modifier visible only at render time, do you just unclick the modifier's eyeball button, and make sure its camera button is clicked?

Comment: I would love if you could add some images to the answer, as following these steps doesn't give me the expected result (no displacement, or if I click "use subdivision" the faces of the mesh just separate or become solid color)

Answer (score 6):

By default, using the 'Displacement' plug in the *Node Editor* does not truly displace the mesh, but "bump maps" it instead, which essentially means that it approximates the appearance of displacement without actually displacing it. In order to *actually* displace the mesh, you are going to have to use a different techique.

Although there are a variety of ways to do this, the standard way to displace a mesh, instead of using node 'Displacement', is to use the *Displace* modifier. To apply your node setup to the *Displace* modifer, choose a texture in the modifier panel, then select that texture and edit using the *Node Editor*.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've tried this now and the displacement just moves my whole plane, what am I doing wrong now?

Comment: @LeoSutton You need to use a simple subdivision surface modifier first. *Displace* only acts on vertices, so you need to use subdivision to give your plane more vertices for it to act on.

Answer (score 0):

Time for update ... **True Displacement** (called also micro-displacement) ... you make it work in three steps ...

### **1. Render Engine**

... is still available for **Cycles** render engine and still under **Experimental** *Feature Set* ... *Dicing Rate* specify details in pixels.

[image]

### **2. Modifier**

Add *Subdivision Surface* modifier and enable **Adaptive Subdivision** this feature is available (appears) only for modifier stacked as last (if there is more modifiers).

[image]

### **3. Material**

Under *Material Properties > Settings > Surface* switch from *Bump* to **Displacement** ...

[image]

... and under *Shader Editor > Add > Vector >* **Displacement node** ... for input socket use your height map or procedural texture ... output socket plug into *Material Output > Displacement* socket.

[image]
[image]