# Procedural Vue-like materials with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Is there a way to make procedural materials like the ones [here](http://www.quadspinner.com/products.aspx) in Cycles for rocks, sand, landscapes, etc.?

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example image of rocks]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. [Cycles does have procedural textures](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures) if that's what your asking.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, my question is more can this be done with blender cycles for example materials like this http://nukeation.deviantart.com/art/My-Vue-7-Material-Palette-110562439 with blender procedural materials ?

Comment: Here's [what I whipped up in a few minuets](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/62204). Is there something specific in those examples that you want to know if is possible to recreate in blender?

Comment: Thanks , can you give a screenshot from the node editor so that i can use this for learning how to make a material like this for example with the  cycles node editor

Comment: Here is the [node setup](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/62205). Note that this used the [experimental cycles displacement](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Materials/Displacement) (see [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/why-wont-the-material-node-displacement-work-in-cycles) for more info)

Comment: @gandalf3 Hi, why don't you add your comments and node setup as an answer?

Comment: @stacker I added an answer, but the question is a bit broad.

Answer (score 8):

I would say **yes**.

Here is an example I made in a few minutes entirely with material nodes:

[image: Render]

### Node setup:

[image: Node Setup]

Note that the color ramp near the bottom of the screenshot is going from `0` to `3` (to make the displacement stronger). To make colors darker or lighter than `1` or `0` you must [type the values in directly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/number-button-min-max-limits).

Also note that the above image is rendered with Cycles [experimental displacement](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html).
To enable this you must [enable experimental features](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/experimental_features.html) in *Properties > Render settings > Render > Feature Set*:

[image]

This enables the [*Displacement* settings](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html) in *Properties > Object Data*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , for the node setup . Now if i want every rock different then i must you add the new vector tranform node . It allows to change coordinates between different spaces, World, Object or Camera

Comment: @bside That would do it

Comment: You forgot to add the `Veronoi Crac` node setup (and possibly the ColorRamps values and colors - tried to figure out a nice setup myself)... for the rest, the setup is working very nice for a Sea Shell I'm making. Thank you!

Comment: @DerGolem I've uploaded the .blend. Enjoy :)

Comment: Oh, thank you! In the meanwhile, I used a Standard Voronoy/Intensity which also worked well. Thank you again, Gandalf. Your answers are like mini tutorials. Always very well done.