# Issue with arraying an object along a curve

Tags: modifiers

Here's what I'm currently seeing (note that the stretching as the array continues out isn't intentional. I wish the objects to all be button-like, similar to the one closest to the curve):

[image: Issue with arraying along a curve]

I've ensured all transforms/rotations/etc. are *Applied* to both the curve object and the arrayed mesh. All my origins are where you'd expect them to be. Any ideas?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gapj2ctxnmzyrz9/columns2%204.blend?dl=0) is the .blend file, if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key <kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. If you want them to continue to change shape, then you may have a problem, but if the following is good, then so are you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why did that work?

Comment: @JoshuaKing The _Curve modifier_ is very weird and relies on many strange inputs (LocRotScale mainly and probably more). Also, if my answer helped, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted, but how did you know that? Have you just run into exactly this sort of problem before?

Comment: @JoshuaKing Sort of. I don't think I've ever used a curve modifier and had it work perfectly on the first try, so over time I've developed a sort of instinctiveness in knowing what'll fix it. For you for now, I'd suggest trial and error. I still do a lot of that, too. :) There probably is someone out there who can tell you exactly why what I did works and how to replicate the results in the future, but I am not that person. Sorry.

Comment: Noted. In any case, here's what you helped me model: 

http://i.imgur.com/2N1RbyF.png 

I was shooting for something like this:

http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/gothic-stone-patterned-columns-architecture-supporting-intricate-arcade-screens-decorated-spiral-motives-armillaries-40509418.jpg

Comment: @JoshuaKing That's a very impressive model! I'm I may critique, you could use a _Displace object modifier_ for the chips that have been weathered away. I talk a good bit about it [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51408/how-to-create-procedural-surface-defects-with-cycles).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40799/discussion-between-joshua-king-and-shady-puck).