# Material to generate a mountain

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, add-on

While trying to find some information about low-poly mountain, I end up finding this image explaining the material the person used to make his mountain and I thought it look really cool, but it was with 3DS Max:

[image]

I tried to replicate it with Blender with no success. Can anyone point out how to make something like that with Blender?

EDIT:
With the Ant Landscape, I got this :) [image]

Comment: Congrats, that's the better solution to make mountains. Btw, you may also consider to triangulate the mesh to make better low-poly look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leon's [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4973/12) is correct, you can use [Heightmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap) along with the *Displace* modifier to achieve this but depending on the level of control and flexibility you might want, a *much* better way to do this in Blender is to make use of the [*Ant Landscape*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape) addon.

Open *Use Preferences*, go to *Addons* and find it under *Add Mesh*.

[image]

In the *3D viewport*, add a new object with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Landscape* and play with the settings that appear in the *Toolshelf*. BlenderCookie also has a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfOdEGL9Gk8) ([archived](https://cgcookie.com/archive/tip-using-the-ant-landscape-add-on/)) on how to use this.

[image]

To achieve the lowpoly look while editing the object, keep your subdivisions low and to achieve the lowpoly look after. You can triangulate the mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and also make use of the *Decimate* modifier.

Comment: Bingo. I'd rather choose that addon for such case, too. :)

Answer (score 6):

In fact, it's more like a question on how to use the Displace modifier, since your image shows the man was using a Displace modifier with a texture to generate that in 3DS Max.

Although different softwares got different steps and flow on getting the same result, Blender got it's way to do this, there is Displace modifier in Blender, too, and also, can be controlled with textures, vertex groups, and even more freely by using specific images. You can also use it several times to accumulate as a combined result. As shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using the Displace modifier with the textures you used but it doesn't look at all at what you have: http://i.imgur.com/J7fI0oS.png (with a grid) and http://i.imgur.com/u3Az4zJ.png (with a plane).

Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I used grouped vertices to limit mountain area, after seeing your image, I guess something needs to optimize on the vertex group. To be hornest, such way is complicated and needs more tweaking than the addon that iKIsR mentioned. So I personally suggest you use it, and it seems nice on your updated image. :)

Comment: The thing to remember with the displace modifier is that it "displaces" geometry - it doesn't create geometry. To get a detailed result you need to subdivide the mesh enough to show the detail. A subsurf modifier or two with high subdivision levels before the displace modifier can be helpful for that. @Enigme - try increasing the strength of the modifiers or the brightness/contrast in the textures (under colors).

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better to do it with a displacement modifier (like Leon said), but it is possible to create a "mountain" with just materials in Blender Internal (the only issue is you can only see it when it is rendered).

Viewport:
 [image]

Rendered:
 [image]

The trick is to use the displacement slider under geometry in the textures tab:

[image]

You can also do the same thing in Cycles:

[image]

The node setup:
[image]

Make sure when you do it in cycles to enable experimental settings in the properties, and to set the displacement to *true* in the *object data* tab:

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a note about [doing this in cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1719/599) too?