# How can I do a detailed landscape?

Tags: scripting, uv

I am a beginner in the use of blender and in this community, so I do not know if this is the appropriate place to make these comments. I'm trying to make blender the landscape that is shown on the next page [Landscape construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136592/generate-landscape-by-cutting-a-plane-in-3d/136608?noredirect=1#comment368763_136608), since I think blender can do it in a faster way, but I still do not know how to do it, if someone knows how to do it would be a great help, on the page mentioned above, show each step of the construction of the landscape in detail. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Following the advice of @cegaton this image is the result that I want to achieve,following the steps indicated in the web page of the hyperlink shared by me.

[image: image desire]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57943/i-need-to-do-a-very-simple-terrain-with-texture-map/57945#57945 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/is-the-add-landscape-button-really-just-a-pre-made-mt-mckinely/28015#28015

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/material-to-generate-a-mountain/4974#4974

Comment: @cegaton Very interesting the information of the link that you have shared, but it would be of more help if you could show some steps already done, to have some idea of how I can do it since I am learning to use blender

Answer (score 1):

As of 2.78a, you can use adaptive subdivision by turning on experimental features, using a subsurf modifier, and checking the "adaptive" checkbox in the subsurf options. Then, you can head up to the object's node tree and connect a procedural texture to the "displacement" input of the material output. Depending on what kind of landscape you want to do, you can mix procedural textures using the mixrgb node. Noise alone yields a connemara-ish landscape, Voronoi + waves creates a desert and Voronoi + Noise creates alpine mountains.

Comment: Thanks for the information on how subsurf modifier works and the landscapes that are achieved with it, but my doubt is still how to do the division of the plane to get the picture mountain, please show me a few steps to better understand the idea you propose.

Comment: The secret is thinking about landscapes as layers of displacement, so you can create landscapes out of procedural textures. See thenoise texture? Now imagine it as a heightmap, with the vertices displaced according to its data. T'is the whole principle. To learn more about it, just watch this video by gleb alexandrov: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlh9rrjG29k . There's a part about terrain generation at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the ANT Landscape addon. It comes with Blender, but you'll need to activate it from the [Add-Ons Preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/addons.html).

Next, go to Add (Shift+A) > Mesh > Landscape. In the bottom left of the 3D View (bottom of the Tools panel) you'll see a bunch of options for the landscape you just added. (Most tools have options here that you can tweak after the fact.) If you don't like the way it looks, try changing the type and/or random seed here.

[image: Landscape options]

Answer (score -5):

You can try to use this addon : *Add Mesh : ANT landscape*

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape

Comment: Please include some steps as to *how* the user could recreate that landscape using the add-on you suggest within the answer itself.

Comment: @RayMairlot  Sorry but it is too difficult for me.