# Getting "experimental" true displacement to work

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, uv, node-editor, displacement

I have been trying to achieve a true mesh displacement on meshes for quite some time, without ever getting it to work.

If I understand it correctly, this experimental feature would allow me to easily **displace** the vertices of a mesh - or to **create** new mesh vertexes where needed - to get a displaced mesh in the result, based off an image, but without using a bump map (simpler, faster?).

This all sounds very exciting in theory, but I am having a really hard time finding examples or tutorials that are both recent and whose links function. So I think there is the need for a question here which will call upon detailed and recent answers to bridge that gap.

I'll start with a simple **ico sphere**:

[image]

Then, [following Aldrik's answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/why-wont-the-material-node-displacement-work-in-cycles), I will change the **Feature Set** to the **Experimental** one:

[image]

I then add a pink granite image to the mesh:

[image]

**Mark Seams, Unwrap**, add image in the **UV Editor**:

[image]

[image]

and finally, in the **Object Data** panel, change the **Displacement** method from **Bump** to **True** as explained [in Aldrik's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/why-wont-the-material-node-displacement-work-in-cycles):

[image]

no result yet:

[image]

if I click "Use Subdivision" this is what I get (so I won't click it right now):

[image]

Looking into the Node Editor, nothing seems to have changed with the Displacement of the mesh:

[image]

so I tried to replicate the node setup seen in [the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjM4r.png) of [this similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/what-is-the-difference-between-the-displace-socket-and-a-bump-map) (**Linear** isn't an option, **Clip**, **Single** and **Repeat** are):

[image]

... but the result is a white ICO Sphere, similar to Image 1.

So, can the "**Experimental Feature Set**" be used to create actual **displacement**, and modify a mesh?

This is what I'm trying to obtain - but with the image of the texture actually displaying on the mesh (image from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/what-is-the-difference-between-the-displace-socket-and-a-bump-map)):

[image]

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34108/how-to-add-a-displacement-map-on-a-plane-using-procedural-textures-with-a-layer/34271#34271

Comment: I don't recommend true displacement in blender yet. Here is why: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45874/7777

Comment: Thanks Jerryno for highlighting the limits of this technique. In my case it is perfect for what I'm trying to do, and I think it is very quick compared to creating bump maps with crazy bump, etc. If you have a quick and easy way of getting the same results that is supported and not experimental, feel free to post it in a comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A UV Sphere is a better mesh to try this feature on (is made out of quads, and not triangles like the Ico Sphere and should subdivide better).

You need to plug the displacement texture to the **[displacement socket](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html?highlight=displacement)** on the material output.

Render Feature set has to be in **Experimental**.

Displacement in the mesh section has to be set to **True** or **Both**.

To preview, you have to be in **Rendered Mode** in the 3D viewport. Other Shading modes will not reflect the displacement.  Any changes made on the settings will not refresh in real time, you have to exit Rendered Mode (go to Solid or Wireframe Mode) and re-enter Rendered Mode to update (alternatively you can press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice).

The more subdivisions you have on your mesh, the more detailed the displacement, but it will also have an impact on the performance of your computer.

Remember that this is still an "**[experimental](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html)**" feature, so expect some unexpected results...

[image]

[image]

[image]
click on the image to enlarge

In my opinion, given that this feature is largely experimental, I'd still use a **[displace modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html?highlight=displace%20modifier)**. Is more predictable, responsive and easier to control. The results can be previewed in real time in solid and texture mode as well. Also, setting some subsurf modifiers in the right order can make things a lot nicer looking, and with a lot more control on the number of subdivisions.
You can always apply the modifiers to make the displacement permanent, which you couldn't do using the displacement node.

Here's the same displacement, but with a displace modifier instead:

[image]

click on the image to enlarge

**UPDATE:**
The option was under the Mesh properties at Blender version 2.76 but in more recent versions it has been moved to Material Properties > Settings > 
Displacement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But could you make an answer where the displacement comes from an image, say the same image as the surface (instead of procedural noise of wave)? Having two identical "Image Texture" nodes and plugging one into Surface and one into "Displacement doesn't work...

Comment: @fabriced Do not use **Use Subdivision**

Comment: This is awesome! Best answer on this topic yet I think... Great visual references as well (that last cube is pretty cool!) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The result is very different though (but maybe I'm using the displace modifier wrong): http://i.imgur.com/DBQx2zZ.jpg

Comment: @fabriced your picture is unclear. If you are in edit mode you have to enable the modifier for edit mode http://i.stack.imgur.com/FbWim.png. Otherwise show images on object mode.

Comment: Sorry. Here is what it looks like with "display modifier in edit mode" turned on, as you can see, the Solid view doesn't display a displaced mesh, and displacement is less than obvious (compare to previous screenshot of Experimental Displacement): http://i.imgur.com/FaaNkem.png

Comment: "Displacement in the mesh section has to be set to True or Both." is this still true in Blender 2.78? I can't seem to find the option anymore

Comment: The option was under the Mesh properties at Blender version 2.76 but seems to have moved to the Material properties at 2.78.

Comment: @RichSedman answer updated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Time for update ... **True Displacement** (called also micro-displacement) ... you make it work in Blender in three steps ...

### **1. Render Engine**

... is still available for **Cycles** render engine and still under **Experimental** *Feature Set* ... *Dicing Rate* specify details in pixels.

[image]

### **2. Modifier**

Add *Subdivision Surface* modifier and enable **Adaptive Subdivision** this feature is available (appears) only for modifier stacked as last (if there is more modifiers).

[image]

### **3. Material**

Under *Material Properties > Settings > Surface* switch from *Bump* to **Displacement** ...

[image]

... and under *Shader Editor > Add > Vector >* **Displacement node** ... for input socket use your height map or procedural texture ... output socket plug into *Material Output > Displacement* socket.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for following up with this!