# Cycles true displacement magnifies mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, experimental-features

When I attempt to use true displacement in cycles render it looks correct under the "materials" viewport but, when I render/Pre-render it looks like it magnified the map/procedural texture. Any ideas on where I'm messing up?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?... The Material shading view will show displacement as bump (2D), not as real geometry displacement. True displaement's geometry will only be visible in rendered view.  To control the amount of displacement you can change the values. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50442/1853