# Displacement not working properly - following Blender Guru rope tutorial

Tags: displacement

this is my first post so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm following this Blender Guru tutorial: https://youtu.be/1drRNphACMc?t=955

At the 15:55 mark he changes Displacement to True, which I've done, but my result doesn't look like his. Everything up until this point has, and I can't see any differences between what he's done and what I've done.

Mine looks like this instead:

[image]

And when he adds a Subdivision Surface modifier, it gets more bumps which make it look more ropey, but mine just goes back to looking completely smooth, like so:

[image]

Any advice on where I might be going wrong here?

Comment: before, just after setting displacement to "true" he did a double tab to enter/exit edit mode (16.03), and that made the rope became much more "influenced" by the bump...  only after he added a subsurf and also activated "adaptive"... are you sure you followed strictly his workflow?

Comment: I've definitely done all of that to the letter :/ Feeling a bit lost. I must have some other settings incorrect I think, but I don't know what could be causing it?

Comment: Related: [Getting “experimental” true displacement to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work/50442#50442)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to set your displacement map to **non color data** in the node editor.

Here is an example of microdisplacement with the map set to **color data**:

[image]

And this is the same image, set to **non color data**:

[image]