# Displacement not working with node editor

Tags: texturing, displacement

I am having this problem that i set up everything right for the displacement (I think) but it is still not working. I am making a paper texture and I just need some help.

I have the mapping done with the texture Coordinate. That is hooked up to a noise texture and then in the Voronoi texture. After that all I hooked it up in the displacement and nothing is working.

If you want you can look at the file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gdmaL9oywBdCL1RgjhnlAxtroULAkqlU?usp=sharing

I have a plane set up for the material on the second layer. On the first layer my whole project is setup. So you only need to have a look at the first layer.

Note that the texture itself isnt hooked up yet to the material output and that is because i needed to check if the displacement texture looked right.
[image]

[image: click on the image to view the nodes bigger]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you upload some screenshots of your node setup and settings? don't rely on people downloading your file.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Did you set the feature set to "experimental"? Did you set the displacement to "true" or "both"?

Comment: No I didn't set the feature to experimental and I cannot find the place where I can change the displacement setting. I have looked for it because I am following a video on yt for this material but the place where the yt video changed it there wasnt such a feature for me

Comment: I just set the feature set to experimental and restarted Blender but I dont  see a displacement option under the object data panel

Comment: I have just added a image to show that there isn't a panel for displacement in experimental feature set

Comment: If you actually read the linked answer it shows you where to find it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work. The option is in the material properties>settings>displacement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI0BY.png

Comment: Ok awesome! I wasn't looking at the right place but it is solved right now. Thanks alot!