# True displacement not working in Blender. Any advice?

Tags: texturing, displacement

I'm following Andrew Price's (Blender Guru's) tutorial on how to make photoreal rope in Blender. As part of the tutorial, we are applying material and displacement from a free texture from Poliigon (link to texture: https://www.poliigon.com/texture/fabric-rope-001). After applying the material and displacement, we switch the displacement from the "Bump" setting to the "True" setting and hit Tab twice to see the results (link to video at time where those instructions are given: https://youtu.be/1drRNphACMc?t=868). In the video, the geometry of the mesh changes to have this very bumpy, ridiculous look. Mine looks like this instead:

[image]

As you can probably see, it is very flat and not textured at all. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch to rendered shading. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work

Comment: I believe render mode / render shading is on, but I might be confused about what you mean by rendered shading. When I click SHIFT + Z, I put my image into rendered shading. Is that what you are referring to? @cegaton

Comment: Check the direction of your normals - it looks to me like the lighter sections of the texture are causing a displacement 'inwards' - the opposite direction to what is expected.