# Color ramp to bump map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, texture-coordinates, height-map

I have this black and gold sort of paint melting cycles material. I would like to add depth to the texture using the Color ramp node. How can I create displacement using my current node setup?

My node layout:

[image: Here are my nodes:]

Here is my slightly Photoshopped test render:

[image: test render]

Comment: have you tried to plug the output of your ColorRamp into the Height input of a Vector > Bump node, then plug the output of your Bump node into the Normal input of your two Principled BSDF? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the texture as a bump map on the whole material

[image]

Or you can add a Vector>Bump node to add the bump map to one or more of the shaders you are using.

[image]

If you need real displacement, not just bump map, enable the experimental feature set and then change the displacement to True or Both in the material.

More info: [Getting "experimental" true displacement to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work/50442#50442)