# How to generate isosurface materials?

Tags: mesh, materials

Since bump mapping cannot modify the actual shape of an object and hence the flat shadow, I want to know is there is any way to generate an isosurface material
like this in blender?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work