# Displacement not working correctly

Tags: modeling, texturing, displacement

So I have some displacement for the top plane of my model. The displacement raised the plane. I figured out the cause. It happened because the edges were somehow split while I was modelling. BUT, when I merge the vertices, the displacement ceases to exist. It looks as if I applied a bump map. I tried modelling again but in vain. I am following a tutorial from youtube.

[Here is a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A245FOyn9Ak&t=1807s)

I'll upload pictures for references

[image]

[image]

Here is my node setup:

[image]

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Upload blend file for us to look at.

Comment: how do I upload with textures?

Comment: first in the UV Editor, Image menu > Pack the image. Then upload your blend in https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: that option isn't there for me. I can give you the link to the textures tho.

Comment: You can do it via File > External Data > Pack All into blend. Could you try to untick smooth shading (if it's on) in the mesh properties > Normals > Auto smooth

Comment: I uploaded the file. And I uploaded before I saw your message so I haven't unticked smooth shading

Comment: Not really a direct answer: I would create a really dense mesh. Like 5 million polys. Then add a displacement modifier and apply it. Then add a decimate modifier to get down to low poly again. It will be very slow depending on your computer. But waiting a couple of minutes for the decimate modifier is still ok. It does all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

With the *Displacement* node plugged into the *Material Output* you're trying to give real displacement to your object. It won't work if you don't give it enough topology, you need to subdivide it.

Also, the *Image Texture* is supposed to be plugged into the *Displacement Height* input.

I'm not sure I would use this kind of effect for a hardsurface object though, it works fine for organic object but here it will require a very high-poly mesh, you should try to fake 3D with a *Bump* node.

Here I've subdivided the mesh to get the *Displacement* effect:

[image]

Here it's a low-poly with 3D faked with a *Bump* node (plugged into the *Normal* input of the *Diffuse* this time):

[image]

Comment: How can a bump node work when I want displacement?

Comment: If I want the same output as the tutorial, what should I do? or is it not possible in blender 2.8?

Comment: Bump fakes displacement right? I want actual displacement, where the geometry is modified.

Comment: I don't think he uses real displacement in this tuto and anyway it was not possible in 2.7, you could do it with the Displace modifier though. If you want real displacement, as I said, you need to increase dramatically your topology (subdivide it) otherwise the mesh doesn't have anything to displace   ;)

Comment: he connects the colour node directly into the displacement node. Also, if there is a displacement modifier, what's the use of the node?

Comment: in 2.7 you can plug a Bump into the Output displacement but it only fakes 3D, you can't make any real displacement in the 2.7 node editor (or maybe experimental), you can displace with the Displace modifier though, but same thing, you need a high poly, otherwise Blender can't displace anything

Comment: also, it did work in the model that has it's edges split. but as I said, if I join the edges, everything goes south. He talks about micro displacements. It does seem that his mesh deforms. Although I know for a fact that displacement need a high meash amount, I couldn't understand what I saw

Comment: Can I talk to you in a private chat? I'm new to blender stack exchange so I'm not aware.

Comment: maybe you'll find the explanation here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work

Comment: but what makes you believe that he does real displacement in the tuto?

Comment: I increased the subdivisions, and the displacement is visible. but I'm encountering more problems which frankly, I don't know how to explain.

Comment: well in his video, you can see stuff protruding out of those faces. that's why I thought it was real displacements

Comment: at what minute?

Comment: for pretty much the whole video. maybe go to 8:28