# How to displace face within object

Tags: modeling, displacement

I cannot - for the life of me - figure out how to displace this section selected in the pic. I know I need to use the displacement modifier but I can't subdivide this section in order to do so. Also, it's sort of creased and angled so I don't know if that matters. Basically I want the masterlock imprint on the lock itself. I know the basics on how to use the modifier but I just can't seem to make this happen. If there's an easier way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm very open to it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can't subdivide at mesh level, try to use Vector Displacement with  Adaptive Subdivision enabled (this is also called Micro Displacement) when Experimental features are enabled for Cycles ... that is happening at rendering level, so you have to enable under Material Properties > Settings > Surface > Displacement > Displacement ...https://imgur.com/78ScF43

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I'm a bit confused, I was able to enable the experimental features but I don't see anything here in regards to "adaptive" or "micro" subdivision. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Edit: My comment was mean to be a tip to search ... Adapt.Sub. is feature of Subdiv modifier (appears if placed as last in modifier stack) ... "micro-displacement" is generaly used term in 3D ("true displacement" in blender) specify a technique. It is not a one click in blender, there is a few steps to make it work in blender so search for tutorial (there should be a lot of thouse). https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308697/2214