# Creating children's bracelet beads with engraved and colored letters

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, shaders

I've been trying to recreate these beads in blender

[image]

How can I achieve the rounded bottom engraving as well as the slightly beveled edges of the letters and then add color to the letters?

I tried different methods but wasn't really successful yet.
I used a uv map with an image texture of the letter for displacement modifier on a grid filled face of a beveled cylinder, I tried using a pointless shader with a color ramp for the two colors but I can't make the colors work. The bead is unicolored.

I also don't see modeling the engraving and then shrink wrapping a colored letter onto the object, texture painting is to irregular.

I'm not new to blender but still hit the ceiling with these kinds of things.

Displacement mapping inside a shader wasn't working since the displacement isn't deep enough. Is there a way to fix this?

I thought this would be straight forward but I've been stuck for longer than I'd like to admit :')

Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated!

EDIT: I want to create the single beads, it's not about creating a whole bracelet.

Comment: True Displacement will work for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308697/2214 ... or simpler - just normal or height map should work as well. Probably show us your fails with these tries.

Comment: I feared that in the end it would be quite simple as that. It worked perfectly, I set up a displacement map and a colored letter to fill the embossing! Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* simply cut the letters into the beads.
Might take some time if you need a whole alphabet, though ;)

1. Cut the letter shape into the bead (*Knife project* works well)
2. Give it a second material
3. *Inset* the shape and *Extrude* down
4. *Bevel* the edges

<sup>(font name: Arial Rounded)</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thank you mate, I managed to create my desired effect using true displacement recommended by @vklidu! But will try your suggested method too!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :)